# Full-size wired keyboard with trackpad

Tags: mac, keyboard, touchpad

Does anyone make a full-size wired keyboard that has an integrated trackpad, preferably Synaptics?

I see a lot of them out there that are designed as if the keyboard and trackpad were ripped off of a laptop.  (So as to emulate the carpal-tunnel experience of typing on a laptop without the convenience of having a laptop?  Getting someone to whack your hands with a mallet would be cheaper.)  And there are a few that a full-size, but wireless, like the Logitech DiNovo.  But I don't see anything that looks like a real keyboard plus a trackpad that is also wired.

Oh, and it needs to work under MacOS.

Comment: IBM markets their Ultranav as "full-size" http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00009APTK/ref=asc_df_B00009APTK941158?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&tag=googlecom09c9-20&linkCode=asn&creative=380341&creativeASIN=B00009APTK.  Not sure if that flies with you, or if the price is remotely reasonable.

Comment: Synaptics touchpad, too, if that helps.

Comment: I'm willing to consider anything, but I'd prefer one where the touchpad is to the side, rather than under my wrists.

Comment: Related, not dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/7873/what-is-a-good-external-trackpad-for-a-mac

Answer (score 1):

See:
[Boring Keyboard with Interesting In-Built Trackpad](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2009/09/boring-keyboard-with-interesting-in-built-trackpad/).
[SolidTek KB-540BU Black USB 88 keys Mini Keyboard with Touchpad built in as mouse](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1472243&CatId=533)

Comment: Yeah, I'd just come across that "boring" one myself.  The press release claims Mac compatibility, but nothing else does.  If nothing else presents itself, I'll give that one a shot.

Comment: Quite a lot of such keyboards can be found here : http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=node%3D12879431&field-keywords=touchpad&x=0&y=0.

Comment: Most of those are wireless; most of the remainder are the spazoid pseudo-laptop keyboards; the few beyond that don't claim Mac compatibility.